# Windows Update Erorr code 1058 disabling itself when started

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, windows-update

I have no clue what is going on, I enable, activate, I set it to automatic, manual activation
STILL NOTHING, Windows Update disables itself when I activate it.
Troubleshooter does not do anything!
I had some other issues today, might it be caused by virus or a physical damage? (God please no)

Running version 19042.804 (20H2).

some screenshots if it will help:

[image: Windows Update showing error — service not running properly]

[image: wuausrv service is disabled]

[image: start wuausrv yields "System error 1058 has occurred."]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>SFC /scannow
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

Comment: Have you performed the DISM system repair steps? What about the Windows Update Troubleshooter that should be linked on the right side of the Windows Update screen?

Comment: Also, there's several such questions showing from MS support forums. Have you tried the steps suggested in them? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/error-1058-when-enabling-window-update-services/5fc15ed9-c849-4f42-89a6-41be90b9239a?auth=1

Comment: troubleshooter did not found anyhing, i ran it at least 3 times and one more time rn

Comment: they dont work because my windows update is disabled and i cant enable it, what they do is to stop it, do stuff and enable it, but mines does not activate, that is my problem basically

Comment: What don't work? Please tell us EVERYTHING you have tried, each and every step, so we know what not to suggest. Also, what build of Windows 10 are you running? Have you tried installing more recent updates manually?

Comment: I have tried everything, going in servises and enableing Windows Update, it just disables it self, i tried enableing it from the CMD with admin, still code 1058

Comment: my build is 19042.804 (20H2) ? not 100% sure how recent it is but im sure it is not the newest

Comment: Yes, 20H2 is the most recent full release of Windows 10. Attempting to restart the service from the GUI and command line is far from "everything", and the link I gave above has several other methods and steps offered in it. Please read it thoroughly and follow ALL of the methods it suggests.

Comment: none of these works, thanks anyway for the effort, but just nothing works for me

Comment: no mather what i do, it always ends up ''System error 1058 has occurred.

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.''
EVEN IN THE SERVICES, like how tf can i enable it, when it says 1058 when enabling it?

Comment: Perform a In-place Upgrade. Download the Setup Assistant from the Microsoft Website and run it: [Click here](https://microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). With the in-place upgrade, you have the option to keep apps and files.

Comment: Please post text as text.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a service "stop updates 10 guard" running and stop it.
Also you cand delete it by running in CMD sc delete SU10guard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).