# Does Repair Upgrade on Windows 10 delete files from app data?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have problems with my windows 10
[Windows Update Erorr code 1058 disabling itself when started](https://superuser.com/questions/1625950/windows-update-erorr-code-1058-disabling-itself-when-started)
the only thing I have left is to do a repair upgrade with the media-creation tool for win10
I have tons and tons of files in C, such as saves, photos, apps, datas
Will that be delted if I select ''Keep files and apps'' , only files on D: (E:) will be ok or the whole C as well?

Comment: If you choose to "keep files and applications" then your personal files will not be lost.  During the installation process only the system drive is affected.  What will happen is Windows is no difference then the installation of a feature update.  Windows will be installed, user profiles will be migrated to the new installation, this includes personal files contained within those user profile directories.  What might not be moved is traditional desktop applications, it's be years since I performed a Reset, and performed and research on the subject.

Comment: [I documented Windows 8+ Reset capabilities awhile ago](https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A83283+Windows+Reset)

Comment: alright thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 10 Repair Upgrade (when you run it) has 3 possible methods to run. I outlined them in some detail below. If you can use Keep Everything, then nothing will be lost.

So to your precise question, Keep Everything keeps all apps, all settings and all data.

Of course, have a backup against the unexpected. No repair but number 3 below will fix a broken User Profile if that is the issue.

> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.